# Finding average settling value after step response

Tags: algorithm, numpy, signal-processing

I'm working with gathering data from a biological monitoring system. They need to know the average value of the plateaus after changes to the system are made, as shown below.

This is data for about 4 minutes, as shown there is decent lag time between the event and the steady state response.

[image]

These values won't always be this level. They want me to find where the steady-state response starts and average the values during that time. My boss, who is a biologist, said there may be overshoot and random fluctuations... and that I might need to use a z-transform. Unfortunately he wasn't more specific than that.

I feel decently competent as a programmer, but wasn't sure what the most efficient way would be to go about finding these values.

Any algorithms, insights or approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This may be a good candidate for http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually get a good start by just analyzing first derivative. Consider process steady if first derivative is close to zero. But please note that this is no 'silver bullet' type of solution, some nasty corner cases to expect.

Anyway based on above, a simple demonstration follows:

```
import numpy as np

# create first some artificial observations
obs= np.array([[0, 1, 1.5, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 7, 9.2, 10.5, 15],
               [1, 2, 6, 6.01, 5.5, 4, 4.7, 3.3, 3.7, 3.65]])
x= np.linspace(obs[0][0], obs[0][-1], 1e2)
y= np.interp(x, obs[0], obs[1])
# and add some noise to it
y+= 1e-3* np.random.randn(y.shape[0])

# now find steady state based on first derivative< abs(trh), but
# smooth the signal first by convolving it with suitable kernel
y_s= np.convolve(y, [.2, .6, .2])
d, trh= np.diff(y_s), .015
stable= (np.abs(d)< trh)[:-1]

# and inspect visually
from pylab import grid, plot, show
plot(x, y), plot(x, y_s[1: -1])
plot(x[stable], np.ones(stable.sum()), 's')
grid(True), show()
```

With output like (where red dots indicates the assumed steady state process):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple method may be to calculate and track a moving average (that is, average the last N samples).  When the average changes by less than a threshold, you can assume it's the steady-state.

The trick lies in choosing N and the threshold appropriately.  You may be able to guess at reasonable values, or you can use several events' worth of data to train the system.

It looks like an interesting project—good luck!